# React Hook useState Constructor with Asyncstorage

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to set the initial state with asyncstorage. Is there a way to do this?

```
const _retrieveUser = async () => {
  return await AsyncStorage.getItem('authUser');
}

const [user, setUser] = useState(_retrieveUser().then(user => user) || null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The initial value will have to be something that's synchronously available. Then you can do your async work in an effect. If necessary, you can render a placeholder while this work is in progress

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
 _retrieveUser().then(setUser);
}, []);

if (user === null) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
} else {
  // return the real component
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  The thing is, if the user is not found, then I want to redirect to the login page.  I guess I could assign another value besides null if the user is not found.

Answer (score 2):

you can pass a function inside useState method to manage the initial state in another simple way:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(async () => {
        const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authUser') //get data and store them in constat
        setUser(data || null) //here the state set self
      }
    );
```

Comment: satisfied answer